Integrate $\int f(x) sn(x,m) dx$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial
To find the antiderivative of a product of a polynomial $f(x)$ and a sine function we can use this formula:
$$\int f(x) sin(x) dx = F'(x) sin(x) - F(x) cos(x) + C $$
where $F(x) = f(x) - f''(x) + f^{(4)}(x) - \cdots $
I was interested in a similar result for the Jacobi elliptic function $sn(x,m)$. So I went online and to my surprise couldn't find anything related, not even the antiderivative of $x\cdot sn(x,m)$. So I tried to imitate the derivation of the above result and got this:
$$\int f(x) sn(x,m) dx = 2m\int F(x,m){sn}^3(x)dx + F'(x,m)sn(x,m) - F(x,m)cn(x,m) dn(x,m) + C $$
where $F(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1+m} - \frac{f''(x)}{(1+m)^2} + \frac{f^{(4)}(x)}{(1+m)^3} - \cdots $
This is not at all useful because it connects an unknown integral to a different unknown integral. So, is there such a formula and if not, why? I would have thought this generalized nicely...
